# IIS 7 - Enable and Remove Kerberos & NTLM authentication

Tags: iis

I've read a number of web articles explaining how to enabled Kerberos and NTML authentication.  What is the process of removing these settings?

```
appcmd.exe set config "mysite" -section:system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication /-"providers.[value='Negotiate']" /commit:apphost

appcmd.exe set config "mysite" -section:system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication /-"providers.[value='NTLM']" /commit:apphost
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note here the `-"providers...` is to remove the settings, so if the above commands are executed, you would be first removing `'Negotiate'` and then `'NTLM'`

If you have additional other providers just add commands for the same and you would be able to remove the same.

Note: To add a new setting use `+"providers...` instead of `-"providers...` in the command.